# Kafka Stream rocksdb metrics not available

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I am trying to monitor KStream rocksdb store.
As per [confluent documentation,](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/monitoring.html#rocksdb-metrics) RocksDB property-based metrics of type *stream-state-metrics* should be available at a metric recording level of **INFO**.

I could observe the MBeans for the same from JConsole.
[image: RocksDB metrics]

However, *kStream.metrics()* does not return rocksDb Metrics.
Setting metric recording level to **DEBUG** does not help either.

Found the following two issues that are similar (but not the same).
However, those are fixed in versions after 2.4.X

- [KAFKA-9355](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9355)
- [KAFKA-9675](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9675)

Also found the following question on SO. But it points to [KAFKA-9675](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9675).

- [kafka streams rocksdb jmx metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446367/kafka-streams-rocksdb-jmx-metrics?rq=1)

What could be wrong?

**Note:**
KStream version : 3.0.0
Broker version: 0.11.0.0

Comment: If your broker version is really 0.11.0.0 as you say, that's the problem.  That's an ancient Kafka version.  Try to install a version newer than 2.4 on the broker side, and see if you can get the metrics to show up.